# Simple formula to ensure two teams get mixed up?

Tags: math

Say I have a number of users who are evenly split between two teams (if there is an odd count then one team will have one extra player).

I want to make sure everyone gets to be on the same team as everyone else over the course of 3 games with team changes after each game.

What's an easy mechanism for doing this for any number of players?

If it makes it easier for the purpose of explanation, I can give each player a number from 1 to N (where N is the number of players).

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we have 6 players, 1 - 6.  You want to create different teams for 3 rounds of play.

For the first round, you deal the players.

```
1    2
3    4
5    6
```

For the second round, you put the winning team first, then the losing team.  Let's assume that the team with player 1 won.  Then the list of players would look like this.

```
1    3    5    2    4    6
```

And you would deal them like this.

```
1    3
5    2
4    6
```

For the third round, you do the same as the second round.  This time, let's assume the team with player 3 won.

```
3    2    6    1    5    4
```

And you would deal them like this.

```
3    2
6    1
5    4
```

With only 3 rounds and many more than 6 players, everybody isn't going to be able to play everybody.  But this shuffling algorithm gives a good mixture and is relatively simple to implement.